# Multiple Sql Server 2008 Database Projects, do they go in a Sql Server 2008 Server Project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I'm a bit new to database projects, but I find that with a bigger team it is a good way to synchronize development.

- I had a single *Database* Project that contained all the tables used by a web app.
- The powers that be want to display data from another database in the web app.
- I create another *Database* Project that represents the tables I need in the other database.
- I create views in the original database that represent tables in the second database (for linq to sql joins mainly)

**Questions**

1. Do I create a Sql Server 2008 *Server* Project and merge both of these databases into it? From what I can tell, a *Server* Project still only represents a single database.
2. If a *Server* Project isn't meant to represent multiple databases, what is it for?
3. I have added steps in our TFS Workflow to deploy changes from the first *Database* Project into our Dev environment on check-in (CI). Assuming a *Server* Project is meant to contain multiple database projects, can I deploy it and have it deploy changes in both databases?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A server project is for server scope objects needed by your solution: endpoints, server principals (logins), server level permissions, linked servers and other similar constructs that are not scoped to any particular database.

Seems to me that what you need is a solution with two projects:

- your original database project
- you reference database project

You need a third project in this solution, a server project, *only* if you must add server scoped objects.

For more details, see [Using References in Database Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386242.aspx).